# How do I catch a UNIX TERM Signal so I can gracefully terminate a PHP process?

Tags: php, unix, signals

I'm running many PHP processes via [Supervisord](http://supervisord.org/configuration.html). Sometimes I need to shut Supervisord down.  When I do so, I have it send a TERM signal to all the PHP processes it has spawned ( using `stopsignal=TERM` in supervisord.conf ).

I'd like to intercept that TERM Signal and gracefully terminate the PHP process.  Can this be done?

I've added this code to my PHP program to try and do this:

```
declare( ticks = 1 );
function gracefully_terminate() {
    echo "\n\ngracefully terminating\n\n";
}
pcntl_signal( SIGTERM, "gracefully_terminate" );
```

Also ... for ease of testing, how do I send a TERM signal to a PHP process via the CLI?  I've tried using `Kill -s TERM #####` ( ##### is the PID of the PHP process ).  Perhaps this is sending the TERM signal, but it's not terminating the PHP process.

Comment: Did your supervisord worker has ability to pause sometime and then stop the worker in `gracefully_terminate()` method? I am struggling in similar [problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34291871/pause-supervisord-stop-event-for-a-while-using-php) . Do u have any suggestion?

Answer (score -1):

I am not that good at php but shouldn't `gracefully_terminate` function have one parameter? Like:

```
function gracefully_terminate($signo)
```

To terminate a process from CLI you should use

```
kill -s SIGTERM #####
```

or

```
killall processname
```